# Initializing a RWMutex crashes in golang?

Tags: go

The following code crashes with the following error, why??

```
package main

import (
    "sync"

)

var foo *sync.RWMutex

func main() {
    foo.Lock()
}
```

outputs:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0xffffffff addr=0x0 pc=0x8125c]

goroutine 1 [running]:
sync.(*RWMutex).Lock(0x0, 0x104000f0)
    /usr/local/go/src/sync/rwmutex.go:86 +0x1c
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox093456788/main.go:11 +0x20

Program exited.
```

it will not happen, when you use one of the following lines

```
var foo = new(sync.RWMutex)
var foo sync.RWMutex
```

for the initialization of the foo variable.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, I recommend you take a look at Go tour https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1

Answer (score 5):

The mutexes are generally designed to work without any type of initialization. That is, a zero valued mutex is all you need to use them. To fix your program, declare `foo` as a value. Not a pointer to a mutex:

```
var foo sync.RWMutex

func main() {
    foo.Lock()
}
```

When you declare `foo` as a pointer:

```
var foo *sync.RWMutex
```

`foo` is a zero valued *pointer (to type `sync.RWMutex`)*, i.e. it does not point to a valid mutex value. `foo` is `nil`. That's why you get the nil pointer exception when calling a method.

However, note that to share the mutex between goroutines/functions, you're going to have to pass them as pointers, after they have been initialized (like above), or they'll not be shared.

From the docs:

> An RWMutex must not be copied after first use.

Docs: https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#RWMutex

Comment: ok so the panic happens because of accessing a struct member w of the RWMutex struct. For this the pointer to this struct, which is nil, must be dereferenced. Strange default of Go, why not initializing like with the new() operator, which also gives back a pointer?

Comment: Because `new` initializes a type completely and then returns a pointer to it. `var` without initialization simply creates a type set to that type's zero value. Changing your original code to `var foo = new(sync.RWMutex)` also fixes the error because `foo` is a pointer to fully initialized mutex.